# Terminer une phrase avec un verbe (d'autant plus, au futur)

Tags: grammaire, verbes, ordre-des-mots, subordonnées

I hesitate because it doesn't seem logical… but I don't know the rules in French!

Is it possible to end a sentence with a verb in French? For example, in English it is (I believe) grammatically correct and perfectly acceptable (at least in colloquial English) to say something like:

> I told him that I am coming.

The above phrase ends with the verb *to come* (*arriver*), in the present tense (*I am coming*/*I am arriving*). I would attempt to translate that as the following:

> Je lui ai dit que j'arrive.

That looks/sounds correct to me in French. However, if I write something like:

> We determine what your monthly budget will be.

equivalently (I think):

> Nous déterminons ce que votre budget mensuel sera.

The phrase in French seems *very wrong*. I don't feel comfortable ending a sentence in the *future tense* in French.

Is there a rule that exists about sentence structure in this regard?

**PS** - My most accurate French translation below

---

J'hésite dans ce cas parce que ça ne me semble pas logique… mais je ne connais pas les règles en français!

Est-ce possible de terminer une phrase avec un verbe en français? Par exemple, en anglais c'est (je crois) correct grammaticalement et acceptable (au moins en anglais familier/courant) de dire quelque chose comme:

> I told him that I am coming.

La phrase ci-dessus termine avec le verbe *arriver* (*to come*), au présent (*j'arrive*). Je tenterais la traduire comme:

> Je lui ai dit que j'arrive.

Cela me semble correct en français. Cependant, si j'écris quelque chose comme:

> We determine what your monthly budget will be.

équivalemment (je crois):

> Nous déterminons ce que votre budget mensuel sera.

La phrase française ne me semble *absolument pas correcte*. Je ne me sens pas confortable en terminant une phrase au *futur* en français.

Est-ce qu'il existe une règle à propos de la structure d'une phrase à cet égard?

Comment: [Que sera sera](http://www.paroles-musique.com/eng/lyrics-Doris_Day-Que_Sera_Sera-translation,t46778)

Comment: Parler comme maître Yoda, tu devra. Car lui, toutes ses phrase avec un verbe, il termine.

Comment: @Rémi Haha, je n'ai jamais regardé Star Wars en français mais j'imagine qu'il soit génial!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Je lui ai dit que j'arrive.

has an issue with the tense but not the position of the verb.  So

> Je lui ai dit que j'arrivais.

I don't think there is something ungrammatical with

> Nous déterminons ce que votre budget mensuel sera.

but I'd use

> Nous déterminons ce que sera votre budget mensuel.

This has nothing to do with the tense, there are other sentences with a verb in a future tense at the last position.  For instance:

> Nous serons environ dix, mais n'avons pas encore la liste précise de qui viendra.

Comment: _Être_ / _to be_ is a special verb. It is a copula. Maybe different rules about word order apply to it compared to ordinary verbs.

Comment: @dangph, I don't think so, inversion in such sentences is common even without copula. _Je ne sais pas ce que chantera Paul au concert ce soir._ for instance.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Regardless of whether or not *Être* is a copula, the word order simply *looks* weird to me in French. For example, *Je ne sais pas ce que chantera Paul au concert ce soir* would translate in English (literally) *I don't know what will sing Paul at the concert tonight*. So I have to consciously re-arrange the words to the correct syntax (what it would be in English) before it makes sense. It makes sense that I have to do it for French --> English as well, but I wasn't sure *how*, so I asked here. Thanks for making it clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Comme il s'agit d'une question sur le français, je vais répondre en français.

> Je lui ai dit que j'arrivais.

est correcte du point de vue de la conjugaison (temps), mais la phrase

> Je lui ai dit que j'arrive.

peut aussi être considérée comme correcte. Elle donne une impression d'action dans le sens où je suis réellement en train d'arriver (en ce moment précis).

> Nous déterminons ce que votre budget mensuel sera.

est grammaticalement correcte, mais ne s'utilise pas dans la pratique. La phrase ne sonne pas bien. La seconde forme est correcte et est celle que l'on emploierait:

> Nous déterminons ce que sera votre budget mensuel.

Et si l'on est dans l'action de le faire:

> Nous sommes en train de déterminer ce que sera votre budget mensuel.

ou encore

> Nous sommes en train de déterminer quel sera votre budget mensuel.

Answer (score 1):

Terminer une phrase par un verbe, même au futur et même une *copule*, est absolument correct. C'est que tous les français en penseront! C'est ce qu'il en est!

L'exemple sur le budget sonne faux, non parce que le verbe est à la fin, mais parce que l'on a du mal à voir pourquoi il y a une inversion du sujet.

> Ce n'est qu'après avoir vérifié vos chiffres que nous déterminons ce que votre budget mensuel sera.